# Integrate $\int \frac{x^3}{3+3x^2} $

Tags: integration

Integrate $$\int \frac{x^3}{3+3x^2} $$

I want to solve it using only this formula-

$$\int \frac{ f(x)}{f’(x)} dx = \ln (f(x)) $$

$f(x) = 3+3x^2$

$f’(x) = 6x$

Therefore, $\frac{1}{6} (x^2) \int \frac{6x}{3+ 3x^2} dx = \frac{1}{6} (x^2) \ln (3+3x^2) + C $

why is my answer wrong ?

Comment: You can't just take out the $x^2$ like that, that's part of the integral

Comment: You cannot take out variables from under integration. For example $\int ax dx = a \int x dx$ but $\int xx \neq x \int xdx$

Answer (score 6):

Your formula:

$$\int \frac{ f(x)}{f’(x)} dx = \ln (f(x))$$

...is wrong! It should be:

$$\int \frac{ f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = \ln (f(x))$$

Answer (score 2):

But $$\ln(f(x))$$ has the first derivative $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int{\frac{x^3}{3+3x^2}\ dx} &=\frac13\int{\left(x-\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\ dx}\\
&=\frac13\int{\left(x-\frac12\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)\ dx}\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&=\frac16\left(x^2-\ln(x^2+1)\right)+C
\end{align}

Comment: I assume 1/6 is from 1/3 multiply by 1/2. Why can u bring 1/2 out ?

Comment: @user59439 have u tried filling in the missing workings yourself?